# Function in anonymous Laravel Blade component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, anonymous-class

I'm working on a Laravel project and trying to create an anonymous Blade component that doesn't rely on a controller. I want this component to have a variable and a method that can be called within it to change the variable's state.

For instance, I have several links (like a navigation bar) and want to change the `activeTab` value when clicking a link.

However, I've noticed that Laravel always looks for the called function inside a controller. How can I change this behavior and implement the functionality I need directly within the anonymous Blade component?

Comment: It sounds like `laravel/folio` or `livewire` would be right up your alley. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/folio

Comment: Other than that, you can create routes that only return a view, and use the `@php` directive to take care of all the logic inside but it won't be a reactive view.